A shorthand for a phrase
I am preparing a note that I would like to refer to matrices whose main diagonals are zero repeatedly. Therefore, I use expressions like this a lot:
"Let $ A $ be a matrix of order $ n $ with zero entries on its diagonal."
Is there a shorthand word for the above sentence?

Oddly, this is sometimes called a "hollow" matrix., but I wouldn't use the term.  It's not universally recognized and, as pointed out in the link, there are other definitions sometimes assigned to that term.

I don't know of one, unless the zeroes along the diagonal is a consequence of something bigger, like being skew-symmetric. I could be wrong, though.
However, nothing is stopping you from making up your own term. Say something like

If a matrix is square of order $n$, with all zeroes along the diagonal, we shall refer to it as a $D_n$ matrix.

and then you can just say

Let $A$ be a $D_n$ matrix.

every time you need to refer to one. Maybe it was a good idea to bake the size of the matrix into the notation, maybe not. It depends on what is in your notes.

I would do the same kind of thing, with the difference that I usually prefer to consider $D_n$ as a set.

@Qise I usually think about it as a group. Properties like this are more commonly given a word-name rather than a symbol-name, I just didn't have the imagination for it right now.
